# Drupal 8 custom form errors

Tags: forms, drupal, error-handling, drupal-modules, drupal-8

If I add a form in Drupal 8 or use a module like Simplenews for the newsletter form, all errors are html5 popups. How can I make it so that the errors have a custom message and are displayed inline? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

hi in your Drupal 8 custom form class you have a function like

> public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
>     }

in this function you are able to do anything about form validation and errors 
thanks

Comment: And if I'm using the Simplenews module? How can I overwrite the template and errors?

Comment: did'nt use Simplenews yet read project documents and code care fully

Answer (score 0):

Try the Clientside Validation module: https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation

Or borrow code from it.  In either case, note that (as of 2018 February 1) the development branch has commits a year-and-a-half more recent than the 'recommended release'.